# How to write Unicode string to text file in R Windows?

Tags: r, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I've figured how to write Unicode strings, but still puzzled by why it works.

```
str <- "ỏ"
Encoding(str) # UTF-8
cat(str, file="no-iconv") # Written wrongly as <U+1ECF>
cat(iconv(str, to="UTF-8"), file="yes-iconv") # Written correctly as ỏ
```

I understand why the `no-iconv` approach does not work. It's because `cat` (and `writeLines` as well) [convert the string into the native encoding first and then to the `to=` encoding](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Writing-Unicode-Text-into-Text-File-from-R-in-Windows-td4684693.html). On windows, this means R converts `ỏ` to `Windows-1252` first, which cannot understand `ỏ`, resulting in `<U+1ECF>`.

What I don't understand is why the `yes-iconv` approach works. If I understand correctly, what `iconv` does here is simply to return a string with the `UTF-8` encoding. But `str` is already in `UTF-8`! Why should `iconv` make any difference? In addition, when `iconv(str, to="UTF-8")` is passed to `cat`, shouldn't `cat` mess everything up once again by first converting to `Windows-1252`?

Comment: I don't know or use R myself, but just reading the documentation, `cat()` outputs character strings "as is", and the `mark` parameter of `iconv()` is true by default, so calling `iconv(str, to="UTF-8")` explicitly marks its output as UTF-8 before it is passed to `cat()`. Maybe `str <- "ỏ"` is not marking `str` the same way? You can use `enc2utf8(str)` or `Encoding(str) <- "UTF-8"` to explicitly convert and mark `str` as UTF-8 without using `iconv()`.  That is probably making a difference to `cat()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think setting the Encoding of (a copy of) `str` to `"unknown"` before using `cat()` is less magic and works just as well. I think that should avoid any unwanted character set conversions in `cat()`.

Here is an expanded example to demonstrate what I think happens in the original example:

```
print_info <- function(x) {
    print(x)
    print(Encoding(x))
    str(x)
    print(charToRaw(x))
}

cat("(1) Original string (UTF-8)\n")
str <- "\xe1\xbb\x8f"
Encoding(str) <- "UTF-8"
print_info(str)
cat(str, file="no-iconv")

cat("\n(2) Conversion to UTF-8, wrong input encoding (latin1)\n")
## from = "" is conversion from current locale, forcing "latin1" here
str2 <- iconv(str, from="latin1", to="UTF-8")
print_info(str2)
cat(str2, file="yes-iconv")

cat("\n(3) Converting (2) explicitly to latin1\n")
str3 <- iconv(str2, from="UTF-8", to="latin1")
print_info(str3)
cat(str3, file="latin")

cat("\n(4) Setting encoding of (1) to \"unknown\"\n")
str4 <- str
Encoding(str4) <- "unknown"
print_info(str4)
cat(str4, file="unknown")
```

In a `"Latin-1"` locale (see `?l10n_info`) as used by R on Windows, output files `"yes-iconv"`, `"latin"` and `"unknown"` should be correct (byte sequence `0xe1`, `0xbb`, `0x8f` which is `"ỏ"`).

In a `"UTF-8"` locale, files `"no-iconv"` and `"unknown"` should be correct.

The output of the example code is as follows, using R 3.3.2 64-bit Windows version running on Wine:

```
(1) Original string (UTF-8)
[1] "ỏ"
[1] "UTF-8"
 chr "<U+1ECF>""| __truncated__
[1] e1 bb 8f

(2) Conversion to UTF-8, wrong input encoding (latin1)
[1] "á»\u008f"
[1] "UTF-8"
 chr "á»\u008f"
[1] c3 a1 c2 bb c2 8f

(3) Converting (2) explicitly to latin1
[1] "á»"
[1] "latin1"
 chr "á»"
[1] e1 bb 8f

(4) Setting encoding of (1) to "unknown"
[1] "á»"
[1] "unknown"
 chr "á»"
[1] e1 bb 8f
```

In the original example, `iconv()` uses the default `from = ""` argument which means conversion from the current locale, which is effectively "latin1". Because the encoding of `str` is actually "UTF-8", the byte representation of the string is distorted in step (2), but then implicitly restored by `cat()` when it (presumably) converts the string back to the current locale, as demonstrated by the equivalent conversion in step (3).

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I didn't get anything to work with the above suggestions.  I'm working in Windows, and that may have something to do with it.  Windows apparently has different encodings for different locales.  But I did find this excellent post by Kevin Ushey:

https://kevinushey.github.io/blog/2018/02/21/string-encoding-and-r/

He suggests the following technique, which worked for me:

```
# Create temp file name
f <- tempfile(tmpdir = tempdir(), fileext = ".txt")

# Vector of crazy stuff
v <- c("Crazy stuff: Ω µ ", "β ¥ ∑ ", "≠ ≤ £ ∞ ؈ ლ ")

# Ensure strings are encoded as UTF-8
utf8 <- enc2utf8(v)

# Use native encoding on file connection
con <- file(f, open = "w", encoding = "native.enc")

# Use useBytes = TRUE
writeLines(utf8, con = con, useBytes = TRUE)

# Close connection
close(con)

# View results
x <- readLines(f, encoding = "UTF-8")
cat(x, sep = "\n")

# Crazy stuff: Ω µ 
# ß ¥ ∑ 
# ≠ = £ 8 ؈ ლ
```

You can see that everything came out perfectly except the infinity symbol, which is turned 90 degrees.  If anyone can figure that out, please leave a comment.

Comment: Concerning the infinity symbol, it appears R is interpreting that as an ascii code 56, which is the number 8.  You can see it here: utf8ToInt("∞").  Not yet sure why or how to fix it.