# Can I convert Unicode into plain text in R?

Tags: r, text, unicode

The data I am using has many characters like `"<U+XXXX>"`. Originally, it looks like this as a data point, `"<U+043E><U+043A><U+0430><U+0437><U+044B>: 673"`.

I am curious what I should use to convert them easily and effectively into ordinary plain texts. I have rows of this Unicode in my table, and I am confused now.

I was looking for ways of conversion online, but most of them don't  work. For example, I have tried this code on my data to convert it from UTF-8 into Latin; it failed.

```
www <- c("<U+043C>")
www %>% iconv(from = "UTF-8", to = "latin1")
[1] <U+043C>
```

Also, I have tried this without arrows. Still, it doesn't convert.

```
www <- c("U+043C")
www %>% iconv(from = "UTF-8", to = "latin1")
[1] U+043C
```

Alternatively, I tried this function.

```
example <- c("<U+041F><U+043E><U+043A><U+0430><U+0437><U+044B>: 58025")
iconv(example, "UTF-8", "latin1")
[1] "<U+041F><U+043E><U+043A><U+0430><U+0437><U+044B>: 58025"
```

Any ideas, folks?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49739800/convert-unicode-to-readable-characters-in-r if that works.

Comment: Thank you, @Shrey --I tried this code. It still doesn't work. Maybe it is such due to different locale. I don't know.

Comment: Alright, maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237358/how-to-write-unicode-string-to-text-file-in-r-windows could help. You can check.

Comment: @Shrey's first suggestion worked for me.  Could you add the code you tried and show the output in your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you type `"<U+043C>"` it is being interpreted as a literal string of 8 characters. Whether this string is interpreted as latin-1 or UTF doesn't matter, since they both encode these literal 8 characters the same way.

What you need to do is *unescape* the unicode strings. The `stringi` package can do this for you, but you need to do a bit of conversion first to get it in the right format. The following function should take care of it:

```r
f <- function(x) {
  
   x <- gsub(">", "", gsub("<U\\+", "\\\\u", x))
   stringi::stri_unescape_unicode(x)
}
```

So you can do:

```r
example <- c("<U+041F><U+043E><U+043A><U+0430><U+0437><U+044B>: 58025")
www <- c("<U+043C>")

f(example)
#> [1] "Показы: 58025"

f(www)
#> [1] "м"
```